# CSS Fixed Position Interferes With Auto Width

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

I'm new to stackoverflow, and coding in general really, so I apologise in advance if its a really stupid question or I've missed something obvious.

I'm having an issue when I set a fixed position for a div, and combine it with auto width.

The CSS i'm using:

```
.headwrapper{
height:100px;
width:auto;
margin-left:90px;
margin-right:90px;
position:fixed;
min-width:1020px;
}
```

When don't include the position:fixed; it all works fine and the width is calculated automatically with 90px margins. However when I include the position:fixed; the auto width doesn't work and the width goes back to the minimum 1020px.

Is there anyway to fix this so the div can change width while fixed in position?

Thanks in advance,
Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your left and right due to you are using position:fixed.
Add this lines to your class:

```
left:0;
right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code [wrapperDiv](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/6j5xY/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="headwrapper"></div>
 </div>



.headwrapper {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    left:90px;
    right:90px;
}
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
}
```